# Unable to retrieve children from all parent objects inside ModelViewSet

Tags: python, django, postgresql

These are classes in my Django project.

```
### Models ###
class Course(models.Model):
   department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

class Department(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

### Serializers ###
class DepartmentFromCourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    department = my_serializers.DepartmentSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = models.Course
        fields = ('id', 'department')

### ViewSets ###
class DepartmentFromCoursesViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Course.objects.select_related('department')
    serializer_class = serializers.DepartmentFromCourseSerializer
```

What I am receiving with my DepartmentFromCoursesViewSet is this response:

```
{
"count": 500,
"next": "https://...",
"previous": null,
"results": [
   "id": 1
   "department": {
      "id": 150,
      "name": "My department1"
   },
   "id": 2
   "department": {
      "id": 151,
      "name": "My department2"
   }
]}
```

But what I would like to get is list of Department objects of all Courses. Like this:

```
"count": 500,
"next": "https://...",
"previous": null,
"results": [
   {
      "id": 150,
      "name": "My department1"
   },
   {
      "id": 151,
      "name": "My department2"
   }
]}
```

I do understand I need to change Serializer, to DepartmentSerializer which will have Meta: model=models.Department and fields=('id', 'name'). But I am unable to receive this object from ViewSet.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if it is the best approach, but this works:

```
class DepartmentFromCoursesViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
   serializer_class = serializers.DepartmentSerializer

   def get_queryset(self):
      # Get all unique IDs of Departments from all Course
      department_ids_set = set(models.Course.objects.all().values_list('department_id', flat=True))
      # Get all Departments filtered by IDs
      return models.Department.objects.filter(id__in=department_ids_set)
```